# How to convert nullable type to its underlying type?

Tags: .net, type-conversion, nullable

I had to store data into DataTable for some particular reason and realised that it does not support nullable types: throws a System.NotSupportedException: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>. Is there a better effective way to convert than enumeration of types and writing a custom code for every nullable type?

Comment: You could use reflection to do that, but why not just assign the value in the data table?

Answer (score 2):

But it supports nullable types, [`AllowDbNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull.aspx) is `true` by default:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("NullableInt", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(1);
table.Rows.Add(2);
table.Rows.Add(3);
table.Rows.Add((int?)null);
```

Use the `DataRow` [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336477.aspx) which support nullable types, for example:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int? value = row.Field<Int32?>("NullableInt");
    // modify the value with SetField:
    row.SetField<Int32?>("NullableInt", null); 
    // or: 
    row.SetField("NullableInt", (int?)null);
}
```

Comment: Second line throws a System.NotSupportedException: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

Comment: @amuliar: Do you use a [typed `DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb.aspx) or a normal `DataSet`/`DataTable`?

Comment: I just used yout first code in newly created application. It throws an exception: 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("NullableInt", typeof(Int32?));
}

Comment: @amuliar: Now i could test my code, earlier i had no IDE. Edited my answer accordingly.